# XRef Relationships in dbml

Tags: oop, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

So I have a database schema like this:

**Users**
   UserId

**RoleUserXRef**
   RoleUserId
   RoleId
   UserId

**Roles**
   RoleId
   Name

With foreign keys defined between User & RoleUserXRef and RoleUserXRef & Role. Basically, I have a one to many relationship between users and roles.

How would I model this in dbml, such that the generated User class has a list of Roles that the user has assigned to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a many-to-many releationship via simple DBML manipulation is not supported currently.  You can extend the partial class to manually create properties, if you really want that sort of functionality "built in".